# Movie: Man investigates his own murder

Tags: story-identification, movie

Early on in the movie, the main character is thrown off a cliff, after that he becomes a watcher. He can follow up on his own murder investigation and see what people are talking about and such. He then finds his own killer in the end.

The movie is ca 1980s, could tip into late 1970s.

Comment: What era is the movie set in?

Comment: It is setup in that era, around 1980. The movie is most likely made in USA, and is english speaking

Comment: I almost thought you were talking about [D.O.A.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094933/) where there is a fall from height in the beginning and then the protagonist is poisoned and has to find his own murderer before he dies. The "watcher" part from your description doesn't line up though.

Comment: I think this belongs in http://movies.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why do people want this migrated?  Unless I'm misreading the question, it sounds like post-death, the character is investigating their own death.  That's on topic here.

Comment: @Keen The movies described feels more like [*Ghost*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099653/) than [*The Sixth Sense*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0167404/), if you get my meaning.  That's why I flagged it.  I'll admit it's borderline, but I think the question has a better chance to get an answer on movies.SE.

Comment: @kylejones Why wouldn't *Ghost* be on topic here?

Comment: @Keen It's not binary on/off-topic for me.  If I ran a clustering algorithm meant to classify SF&F movies and non-SF&F movies based on various features, Ghost would be near the border, but closer to the non-SF&F movies if I were doing the classifying.  This movies feels the same way to me, based on the description.  But since I don't know which movie the OP is referring to, I could certainly be wrong.

Comment: Sounds like _The Invisible_ although that is much too recent. Perhaps an earlier influence?

Comment: @Fruitbat - There was an earlier (overseas) version; http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0298491/?ref_=tt_rec_tt

Comment: The guy is dead, we just follow his ghost around. There is a cop who investigates the murder. The end is that it is his friend who killed him. I saw it in the early 1980s, 1980-1984(ish).